# Adding scripts with document.writeln does not allow to debug in developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I am adding timestamp to the JS and CSS tags. It allows always have newest code if files were changed. Yet, it does not allow debugging JS in developer console.

index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //if not developer mode add timestamp to prevent caching
    var bDeveloperMode=true; 
    var timeStamp = !bDeveloperMode ? ('?_=' + new Date()).valueOf() : '';

    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript2.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript3.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript4.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript5.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');

    function myFunction1(){
        console.log('break here 1');
    }
    function myFunction2(){
        console.log('break here 2');
    }
</script> 
</head>
```

someScript.js

```
function myFunction3(){
        console.log('break here 2');
   }
```

The order of the scripts matters. 
Is there anyway to have timestamp in the script tag and still be able to debug? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the `bDeveloperMode` variable is not defined - that line will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bDeveloperMode is not defined
```

And the rest of your javascript code will not run.

Instead - you can use the typeof and check if it's undefined:

```
typeof bDeveloperMode === 'undefined'
```

Here is the fix to your code:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //if not developer mode add timestamp to prevent caching
    var timeStamp = typeof bDeveloperMode === 'undefined' ? ('?_=' + new Date()).valueOf() : '';
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript2.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript3.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript4.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="../js/someScript5.js' + timeStamp + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');

    function myFunction1(){
        console.log('break here 1');
    }
    function myFunction2(){
        console.log('break here 2');
    }
</script> 
</head>
```

Comment: bDeveloperMode is not an issue. It is global variable that defined elsewhere. Issue is that debugger in chrome does not allow to add break points if JS scripts was added with document.writeln and timestamp. My question is it possible to have different way to import JS scripts for development vs production.

Comment: I just checked it and there is no problem to debug this. How exactly are you trying to debug it?